# Turning an specific Kronecker product to regular matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

hope this question isn't too trivial.

So, I have a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times k}$ and the following Kronecker product:
$$M = \mathbb{I}_{k} \otimes v = \begin{bmatrix} v &0 &\dots &0 \\ 0 & v & \dots &0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & & \dots& v\end{bmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k^2}$$

Is there any simple way to write $M$ as a regular matrix multiplication? Say $M = T\,v\,G$, with T and G of appropriate size. I need the vector $v$ outside the Kronecker product.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, it's not possible to get $M = TvG$ for any $T$ and $G$.  Notably, $M$ has rank $k$, but $v$ has rank $1$, which means that the rank of $TvG$ is at most $1$.

I can't think of a form which is more convenient than that Kronecker product.

Comment: Thanks for the early reply. The thing is that I need the vector $v$ explicitly outside the Kronecker product. Would you say that there is no combination i.e. $T\,v\,G$ that can lead me to $M$? If that's the case, I'll probably have to rewrite my problem in a more suitable form.

Comment: That's exactly what I said